# Impossible to find "Add to Stackoverflow icon" on Pluralsight Skill IQ

Tags: support, pluralsight-iq

I have passed the Skill IQ test on the Pluralsight website. However, I can't find the famous "Stackoverflow" button mentioned by all.
After multiple refreshes and tries on both Stack Overflow and Pluralsight, still nothing.

[image]

The **intended** button that I **don't** find is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a responsive view bug on Pluralsight. On that page, resize your browser window to a more narrow display width and those buttons will appear.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, it's not a responsive issue on my end but more the cluttered UX of the site, you need to go to `view details`

[image]